# DynamodDB: How to update sort key?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

The table has two keys: `filename` (partition key) and `eventTime` (sort key). 
I want to update `eventTime` for certain `filename`. Tried `put_item()` and `update_item()` sending the same `filename` with new `eventTime` but those functions add a new item instead of update.

What should I use for that purpose?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can't. Since it is part of the index, the field is protected. What you should do it to delete the item and add it again with the new sort key.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValueUpdate.html

Answer (score 7):

According to `DynamoDB/AttributeValueUpdate` aws docs:

> You cannot use `UpdateItem` to update any primary key attributes.
>   Instead, you will need to delete the item, and then use `PutItem` to
>   create a new item with new attributes.

Answer (score -2):

In DynamoDB, you can perform a conditional update on an existing item(insert a new attribute name-value pair if it doesn't exist, or replace an existing name-value pair if it has certain expected attribute values).
Refer to the official documentation here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_UpdateItem.html

Also, you may consider using sort keys the right way. Please refer to the suggested documentation here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-sort-keys.html